# How to extract sub string from string using Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have a 9 digit string which include the following details:
First 3 digit represent city code, middle 3 are bank code and last 3 are branch code.

I want extract these 3 from the whole string using Java 8 or functional programming so that whenever I want i can change the implementation.

I have used the old basic structure to get git from one by one using `String.substring(start,end);`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String city = getCityCode("302105202");

        System.out.println("City-" + city);

        String bank = getBankCode("302105202");

        System.out.println("bank-" + bank);

        String branch = getBranchCode("302105202");

        System.out.println("branch-" + branch);

    }

    public static String getCityCode(String micr) {
        return micr.substring(0, 3);
    }

    public static String getBankCode(String micr) {
        return micr.substring(3, 6);
    }

    public static String getBranchCode(String micr) {
        return micr.substring(6, 9);
    }

}
```

How to get these in Java 8 ?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: `.substring(...)` still works fine.

Comment: The way you are doing it seems fine (for your limited purpose) and there is no specifically functional-programming or Java 8 way of doing substrings. You could also look into using regular expressions for greater flexibility with this kind of thing. You can also use String#split for simple cases.

Comment: @LutzHorn yes it works fine but I want to reduce the no. of line. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `String[] codes = codeString.split("(?<=\\G...)");`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need Java 8 features for that purpose.

However, instead of 3 `static` methods, I'd take advantage of Java being an object oriented language. I'd define a `BankAccount` class (or something similar) having 3 instance variables - `city`, `bank` and `branch`.

The constructor of that class will accept the `String` parameter, parse it (with `substring()`, as you currently do), and assign values to the 3 instance variables.

```
public class BankAccount 
{
    private String city;
    private String bank;
    private String branch;

    public BankAccount (String acctStr) 
    {
        this.city = acctStr.substring(0,3);
        this.bank = acctStr.substring(3,6);
        this.branch = acctStr.substring(6,9);
    }

    public String getCity () {return city;}
    public String getBank () {return bank;}
    public String getBranch () {return branch;}

}
```

You might even consider converting the `city`, `bank` and `branch` codes into `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional feature in java 8 with respect to substrings. Your implementation should work fine.